# how to do proper validation and redirect in a grails app

Tags: forms, validation, grails

I've got a create and save methods as follows:

```
def create () {
  def myColorInstance = new Color()
  return (colorInstance: myColorInstance]
}

def save () {
  Date someDate = params.date("somedate", "MM/dd/yyyy")
  int someInt = params.int("someInt")
  color = colorService.add(params.colorname, someDate, someInt)
  if (color.hasErrors())
    render (view: "create", model: [colorInstance: color])
  else
    redirect (action: "list")
}
```

On my layout page I have the following:

```
 <g:hasErrors>
       <div class="alert alert-error">Please try submitting again</div>
 </g:hasErrors>
```

The behavior I'm getting with this is that when the users enter something and it fails validation. They see the message `Please try submitting again` and the url changes to `http://localhost:8080/myapp/color/save` so now when the second time they submit (again without entering anything) then my app fails with message: "Cannot cast object 'null' with class 'null' to class 'int'. Try 'java.lang.Integer' instead"

Whats is the best way to handle this type of scenario? I would like the user to see the error message on top and they should be able to correct the errors again and try submitting again and it should work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set an `int` to null, which is what `params.int("")` may return. `Integer` can be null, however.

```
Integer someInt = params.int("someInt")
```

That will fix your exception, but the reason it is returning null has something to do with your views not passing the data in the first place.

FYI this is incorrect syntax:

```
def create () {
  def myColorInstance = new Color()
  return (colorInstance: myColorInstance]
}
```

Should be:

```
def create () {  
  [colorInstance: new Color()]
}
```

Comment: you are right. it was a stupid typo mistake on my part >_< `render (view: "create", model: [colorInstance: color])` was instead `render (view: "create", model: [colorInstnce: color])` typo!!